# Navigation events not triggered when using LaunchUriAsync (WP 8.1)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

Since it's not possible to activate Bluetooth programmatically, I prompt the user to do it by himself and use this method to open the required settings page:

```
auto uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("ms-settings-bluetooth:");

    concurrency::create_task(Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchUriAsync(uri)).then([](bool success)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            //URI launched
            OutputDebugString(L"Successfully launched settings from URI.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    });
```

However, I need to know when the user comes back to my app, so I can check if Bluetooth has been activated, but LaunchUriAsync does not trigger any navigation events like OnNavigatedTo. Waiting on that task doesn't work either (and wouldn't make sense in my case, since it's done as soon as the settings display).

So, is there a possibility to detect when the user actually comes back?

Comment: LaunchUriAsync should trigger an OnNavigatedFrom event. When the user returns you should get an OnNavigatedTo

Comment: @robwirving In WP8.1 RT you won't get `OnNavigatedTo` (after *Resuming*)- it's fired only when you navigate to a page(`Navigate()`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
When the location services is turned off, I ask the user to turn on the location services and the application opens the location settings.

When the users navigates back from the settings, I wanted the app to load the location based messages.

I created a work around, I used a while loop that's running for 1 minute (the user has 1 minute to turn on the location services)

Here is my code in C#

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));

bool keepRunning = true;
int timesOfRunning = 0;
while (keepRunning)
{
    timesOfRunning++;
    if (timesOfRunning < 21)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        GeoLocationHelper geoLocation = new GeoLocationHelper();
        if (geoLocation.IsLocationServiceEnabled)
        {
            keepRunning = false;
            await RefreshMessages();
        }
    }
    else
        keepRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: I have thought about this too, but it doesn't really help me in that case. Anyway, I have worked around that problem by catching an exception that gets fired if the user attempts to initiate a Bluetooth connection, as suggested in the MSDN Bluetooth documentation for Windows Phone.